# Inconsistent compiling mips

Tags: mips

Usually I don't have problems writing assembly and testing and debugging. But then sometimes the compiler doesn't like the newline character and I don't know why. This problem usually happens with the Berkeley spim simulator

sample code:

```
.text
.globl __start
```

__start:

```
la $a0,crlf
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall

.data
```

crlf:   .asciiz "\n"

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it would be

```
    crlf: .byte 13,10,00
```

This is what I use when \n gives me issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try with

```
crlf:
.db 0x0A 0x0D 0x00
```

Also keep in mind that only Windows uses CRLF for a new line. Most systems use CR only.